# How to extract data from avro/binary response using nodejs(prebuilt libraries)

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I'm using nodejs to send rest api call to azure [Query Blob Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents) to read csv file. I managed to get the response back, but the issue is response is in **avro/binary** format like below.

Here i need to extract **hostname & serial**. How to handle this type and get the data ?
As a side note, I need to acheive this only using prebuild nodejs modules(external libs are not allowed within the platform)

[image: response]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write your own avro parser if no external libs are not allowed. Otherwise, there are npm packages like `avro-js` or `avsc`